# view model returning list of data in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a view model which contains combination of normal properties and List of subscriptions

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
   public String ProjectId { get; set; }

   public String Name { get; set; }

   public List<Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }

}

public class Subscriptions
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to collect data in View Model. Which i will collect from DB context but how do i collect data for list of subscription ?

```
var result = (from p in DataContext.Project join c in DataContext.Subscriptions
                      on p.ProjectId equals c.ProjectId
                      select new ProjectViewModel { ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                                                    Name = p.Name
// List of subscriptions ?
```

Comment: `group` your `c` by `ProjectId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx):

```
var query=from p in DataContext.Project 
          join c in DataContext.Subscriptions on p.ProjectId equals c.ProjectId into subs
          select new ProjectViewModel { 
                                        ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                                        Name = p.Name,
                                        Subscriptions=subs.ToList()
                                      };
```

But is going to be simpler if you use [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) to build your query:

```
var query=from p in DataContext.Project 
          select new ProjectViewModel { 
                                        ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                                        Name = p.Name,
                                        Subscriptions=p.Subscriptions.ToList()
                                      };
```

Comment: after using this it has opened another issue for me....

The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8'.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException","stacktrace":"","internalexception":{ "message":"No NavigationLink factory was found for the navigation property 'Subscription' from entity type 'SSAStatusService.Domain.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel' on entity set 'Project'. Try calling HasNavigationPropertyLink on the EntitySetConfiguration.\r\nParameter name: navigationProperty

Comment: well, that is something related with the serializer that is used by Odata. I don't have much experience using that technology, but I would suggest to create a ViewModel class to Subscriptions to avoid this issue with the navigation properties and to get only the data that you need. If I found another answer I'll let you know but if you like you can create a new question with that issue, I'm almost sure you can fix that configuring OData.